# How make alias to colorize grep command

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to colorize `grep` command output to show different colors for:

- filename
- line number
- search pattern

I found this `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'` but it is coloring only the the word that I am searching for.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2):

May be you could try this:

```
grep -Hn 'search-pattern' tmp.txt
```

This will output:

```
$ grep -Hn 'line 2' tmp.txt
tmp.txt:2:some text line 2
```

Here, "filename", "line number" and "search-pattern" will have different color. It is a normal behavior of `grep`, if you had set `--color=auto`.